# why is this console program silent on Eclipse 3.5.2 and Ubuntu 10.10?

Tags: java, eclipse

Why is this console program silent on Eclipse 3.5.2 and Ubuntu 10.10?  Note that movies are audible given the current setup.

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;

public class JustBeep
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("This is a console program that should beep.");

        // try this
        System.out.print('\u0007'); 
            // this appears as a special character in the Eclipse console
            //  and is not what I want
        System.out.flush();

        // try something different
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bug report suggests it is an ubuntu 10.10 problem.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/beep/+bug/677870